# WebApi 2 Change from Google Authentication OpenID -> oAuth2 - Changes Security handle

Tags: asp.net-web-api, openid, google-oauth

When I started out on my project Google allowed to use OpenID where no real registration was needed.. 
This is now going away, and I have ported the project to the new meths.. BUT
The issue is that the Users will get a new Security token and therefor see the user as a new user.

Has any of you solved that so that I do not need to ask all users to create new accounts, and then for me to link the old accounts with the new accounts?

Comment: This question really needs to be improved but,  this might help https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID  You should be able to migrate your existing opened tokens to Oauth2 tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided that the Google email could be my link to the existing users.
If you are using the standard implementation of Identity in ASP.NET/WEBAPI then change: AccountControler.cs - ExternalLoginCallback

What this does is to looked up the email if the Google user did not exist and add a Login to the existing user like this:

```
        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login);
```

Insert:

```
        //Google Migration. If not existing then check if the Google email exists and if it does the change the LoginProvider key and try to login again
        if (user == null && loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider == "Google" && email != "")
        {
            xxxEntities db = new xxxEntities();
            var existingUser = db.user_profiles.Where(e => e.eMail == (string)email).Where(p => p.created_from == "Google");
            if (existingUser.Count() > 0)
            {
                var existingID = existingUser.Single().userFK;
                var result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(existingID, loginInfo.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    //Now retry the check if the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
                    user = await UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login);
                }
            }
        }
```

To here:

```
        //Now for the normal Check 
        if (user != null)
        {
```

Please note that the lookup is some internal Objects I have, it can be done in a OOTB implementation by adding email lookup to the UserManager, or just do like I do and look it up in your own user admin object